# Can ServiceMAX access shared folder on EC2 server by API?

Tags: ftp, aws, servicemax

we have four serves, server C and S are EC2, and server B and F are out of AWS, all of them are at the same domain.
At the moment, S will get files from shard folder on C and compress to zip, then B will get zip file by ftp from S and unzip file to shard folder on F.

Now We want to move S to ServiceMAX, and move F to other domain.

Here are my questions:
1.  Is it possible to get files on shard folder of C from ServiceMAX directly?
2.  Is it possible to put files to B or F from ServiceMAX directly?

If above are NG, we want use Boomi between ServiceMAX and C/B/F
3.  Is it possible to get files on shared folder on C from Boomi and save them to ServiceMAX attachments
4.  Is it possible to put file to B or C directly, or by SFTP?

Comment: Hi mikezang, and welcome to SFSE! I have a feeling you meant to post your question to [so], as we only deal with salesforce.com and its related products. If I happen to be incorrect, please feel free to [edit] your question with more information so we can assist you!